# How to match this regular expression using TCL

Tags: regex, list, tcl

Kindly give me some input on this. I have the below input for a TCL regular expression.

```
set a {  Descriptor Blocks:
  10.132.224.74 (Tunnel42), from 10.132.224.74, Send flag is 0x0
       Composite metric is (2032896/128256), route is Internal
       Vector metric:
         Minimum bandwidth is 4096 Kbit
         Total delay is 55000 microseconds
         Reliability is 255/255
         Load is 1/255
         Minimum MTU is 1380
         Hop count is 1
         Originating router is 10.128.9.65
   10.135.0.86 (GigabitEthernet0/1), from 10.135.0.86, Send flag is 0x0
       Composite metric is (2033152/2032896), route is Internal
       Vector metric:
         Minimum bandwidth is 4096 Kbit
         Total delay is 55010 microseconds
         Reliability is 255/255
         Load is 1/255
         Minimum MTU is 1380
         Hop count is 2
         Originating router is 10.128.9.65
         Internal tag is 200 }
```

From the above i want to separate like two list element, the regular expression should separate by following word.

> Here there are two interface output is there, one is for

```
10.132.224.74 (Tunnel42)
```

> interface and another one is for

```
10.135.0.86 (GigabitEthernet0/1)
```

> If there is no line starting with "Internal tag is " after the "Originating router
>   is " line it should divide upto "Originating router is " line as a one
>   list element.
>
> If there is a line "Internal tag is " is available after the
>   "Originating router is " line it should divide upto "Internal tag is "
>   as a one list

I am expecting the output like

```
{Tunnel42), from 10.132.224.74, Send flag is 0x0
      Composite metric is (2032896/128256), route is Internal
      Vector metric:
        Minimum bandwidth is 4096 Kbit
        Total delay is 55000 microseconds
        Reliability is 255/255
        Load is 1/255
        Minimum MTU is 1380
        Hop count is 1
        Originating router is 10.128.9.65

10.135.0.86 (GigabitEthernet0/1), from 10.135.0.86, Send flag is 0x0
      Composite metric is (2033152/2032896), route is Internal
      Vector metric:
        Minimum bandwidth is 4096 Kbit
        Total delay is 55010 microseconds
        Reliability is 255/255
        Load is 1/255
        Minimum MTU is 1380
        Hop count is 2
        Originating router is 10.128.9.65
        Internal tag is 200
```

Comment: So, basically you want to separate the Tunnel (i.e. `Tunnel42`) and GigabitEthernet (i.e. `GigabitEthernet0/1`) statistics ?

Comment: yes that is what i am expecting, but it can end up with either "Originating router is " line or "Internal tag is " line

Comment: You can do it in a [single regex](http://codepad.org/OH3VLCTD), but I don't think it will be easy to maintain. I would rather split like in Peter's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `textutil` module to do this easily:

```
package require textutil
textutil::split::splitx $a {\n(?=\s*\d)}
```

This splits the original text into a list of three items: the " Descriptor Blocks:" substring and one item each for the two blocks. It works by finding junctures where a line break and optional whitespace is followed by a digit. The line break is removed, but the leading whitespace and the digit is preserved.

*Core-Tcl solution:*

The substitution

```
regsub -all -line {^(?=\s*\d)} $a \n
```

will split the text into three parts (the first part being the "  Descriptor Blocks:" substring) by inserting an extra line break before each block. This solution obviously depends on only the first line in each block starting with a digit optionally preceded by whitespace. The `-line` option makes `^` anchor after a line break.

Note that this results in a text with three parts, not a list of three elements: if you want that you will need to break the text up at every double line break. Another way to deal with this is to have `regsub` instead insert a character that won't occur in the text, and then split on that character, e.g.

```
split [regsub -all -line {^(?=\s*\d)} $a @] @
```

Documentation: [package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm), [regsub](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regsub.htm), [split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm), [textutil](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/textutil/textutil.html) package

Answer (score 1):

A more generalized approach can be splitting them input into line and parsing them as needed

```
set a {  Descriptor Blocks:
  10.132.224.74 (Tunnel42), from 10.132.224.74, Send flag is 0x0
       Composite metric is (2032896/128256), route is Internal
       Vector metric:
         Minimum bandwidth is 4096 Kbit
         Total delay is 55000 microseconds
         Reliability is 255/255
         Load is 1/255
         Minimum MTU is 1380
         Hop count is 1
         Originating router is 10.128.9.65
   10.135.0.86 (GigabitEthernet0/1), from 10.135.0.86, Send flag is 0x0
       Composite metric is (2033152/2032896), route is Internal
       Vector metric:
         Minimum bandwidth is 4096 Kbit
         Total delay is 55010 microseconds
         Reliability is 255/255
         Load is 1/255
         Minimum MTU is 1380
         Hop count is 2
         Originating router is 10.128.9.65
         Internal tag is 200 }

set tunnelStart 0
set interfaceStart 0

set tunnelInfo {}
set interfaceInfo {}
set result {}

foreach line [split $a \n] {
    if {[regexp {\(Tunnel\d+\)} $line]} {
        # If suppose, we already identified 'tunnelInfo' and extracted it, then that variable won't be empty
        if {$tunnelInfo ne {}} {
            regsub {\n$} $tunnelInfo {} tunnelInfo
            # So, appending it to 'result'
            lappend result $tunnelInfo
            # Then, resetting the 'tunnelInfo'
            set tunnelInfo {} 
        }
        set tunnelStart 1
        set interfaceStart 0
    } elseif {[regexp {\(GigabitEthernet\d+/\d+\)} $line]} {
        # Same reason as explained above 
        if {$interfaceInfo ne {}} {
            regsub {\n$} $interfaceInfo {} interfaceInfo
            lappend result $interfaceInfo
            set interfaceInfo {} 
        }
        set interfaceStart 1
        set tunnelStart 0
    }
    if {$tunnelStart} {
        #Appending each line along with '\n'
        append tunnelInfo $line\n   
    } elseif {$interfaceStart} {
        append interfaceInfo $line\n
    }
}
#Removing the last '\n' alone 
regsub {\n$} $tunnelInfo {} tunnelInfo
regsub {\n$} $interfaceInfo {} interfaceInfo

# At last checking if the variable is not empty, append it to 'result'
if {$tunnelInfo ne {}} {
    lappend result $tunnelInfo  
} 
if {$interfaceInfo  ne {}} {
    lappend result $interfaceInfo   
}
puts $result
```

You can put them in a procedure & call wherever you want to separate the input. If suppose your input has more than one tunnel and interface lines information, you could re-write the code to parse it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks dinesh this what am expecting. In my case both of the interface can be Tunnel or GigabitEthetnet. If that is the case what I can do.

Comment: Thank you dinesh this is exactly what I am expecting.  I appreciate your effort and nice logical thinking.  Is it anyway to do by single regexp I hope some option would be there.

Comment: Nope, to my knowledge, your requirement might not be performed in one single regular expression.